# Cannot use StandardSetController with ContentVersion?

Tags: apex, visualforce, contentversion, standardsetcontroller, pagination

I am trying to display a list of documents stored in Salesforce CRM Content on a VF page using JQGrid. I used OFFSET for paging. Since the number of records is more than 2000, I wanted to use StandardSetController like I did for some other custom objects.

The list was not getting populated when I modified the code. When I looked onto the debug log, everything was fine.

Then I tried hitting the AJAX request generated by JQGrid using browser, a page showing **"List controllers are not supported for ContentVersion"** appeared. That means I cannot use StandardSetController with this object.

Is there any workaround to support paging for more than 2000 records with ContentVersion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://salesforcesource.blogspot.in/2008/09/how-to-support-paging-of-data-in-your.html

Refer the above blog.Earlier days we had no pagination support in salesforce.Still people used custom logics and did the pagination.In our case here too we can apply the logic in above blog to make our pagination

Comment: welcome !Happy to know it did the magic.

Comment: Only thing is that if the total number of records increases, like exponentially, there will be a huge performance hit. For me, the total record count is around 2500 and it does not increase rapidly.

Comment: hmmm upto 10k it should be fine and more means this cannot be used and hence we go for standard controller

Comment: Yes you are right.