# Pagination methods aren't working

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-controller, pagination, standardsetcontroller

After a great deal of searching and effort, I've finally got a working controller that can show ContentVersion documents and paginate them. Upon testing it, though, I found that the `Next` button wouldn't send me to the next set of ContentVersion objects to display. Below is my code, and feel free to use it where you may need it, because I **DON'T** want anyone to have to go through the steps to get to this point again.
ContentVersionController:

```
public with sharing class ContentVersionController {
    private ApexPages.StandardSetController controller;
    private List<ContentVersion> content;
    private List<ContentVersion> pageContent;
    private Integer pageNumber;
    private Integer pageSize;
    private Integer totalPageNumber;

    public ContentVersionController() {
        //controller = new ApexPages.StandardSetController();
        pageNumber = 0;
        totalPageNumber = 0;
        pageSize = 20;
        ViewData();
    }

    public ContentVersionController(ApexPages.StandardSetController con) {
        controller = con;
        pageNumber = 0;
        totalPageNumber = 0;
        pageSize = 20;
        ViewData();
    }

    public static List<ContentVersion> getContentVersions() {
        return [SELECT Id, Title, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion
                WHERE IsLatest = true LIMIT 1000];
    }

    public Integer getPageNumber() {
        return pageNumber;
    }

    public List<ContentVersion> getContent() {
        return pageContent;
    }

    public Integer getPageSize() {
        return pageSize;
    }

    public Boolean getPreviousButtonEnabled() {
        return !(pageNumber > 1);
    }

    public Boolean getNextButtonDisabled() {
        if (content == null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return ((pageNumber * pageSize) >= content.size());
        }
    }

    public Integer getTotalPageNumber() {
        if (totalPageNumber == 0 && content !=null) {
            totalPageNumber = content.size() / pageSize;
            Integer mod = content.size() - (totalPageNumber * pageSize);
            if (mod > 0) {
                totalPageNumber++;
            }
        }
        return totalPageNumber;
    }

    public PageReference ViewData() {
        content = null;
        totalPageNumber = 0;
        BindData(1);
        return null;
    }

    private void BindData(Integer newPageIndex) {
        try {
            if (content == null){
                content = [SELECT Id, Title, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion
                           WHERE IsLatest = true LIMIT 1000];
            }
            pageContent = new List<ContentVersion>();
            transient Integer counter = 0;
            transient Integer min = 0;
            transient Integer max = 0;
            if (newPageIndex > pageNumber) {
                min = pageNumber * pageSize;
                max = newPageIndex * pageSize;
            } else {
                max = newPageIndex * pageSize;
                min = max - pageSize;
                //min = min <>
            }
            for(ContentVersion c : content) {
                counter++;
                if (counter > min && counter <= max){
                    pageContent.add(c);
                }
            }
            pageNumber = newPageIndex;
            if (pageContent == null || pageContent.size() <= 0) {
                ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, 'Data not available for this view.'));
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.FATAL, ex.getMessage()));
        }
    }

    public PageReference nextBtnClick() {
        BindData(pageNumber + 1);
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference previousBtnClick() {
        BindData(pageNumber - 1);
        return null;
    }
}
```

ContentVersionFiles (VisualForce page):

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" controller="ContentVersionController" showChat="false" showHeader="false" showQuickActionVfHeader="false" sidebar="false">
  <apex:form >
    <div align="center" style="display:{!IF(NOT(ISNULL(content)), 'block', 'none')}">
      <font size="1pt">Page #:&nbsp;<apex:outputLabel value="{!PageNumber}"/>&nbsp;out of&nbsp;<apex:outputLabel value="{!totalPageNumber}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>
      <apex:commandButton value="Previous" action="{!previousBtnClick}" disabled="{!previousButtonEnabled}" reRender="pageBlock"></apex:commandButton>
      <apex:commandButton value="Next" action="{!nextBtnClick}" reRender="pageBlock" disabled="{!nextButtonDisabled}" ></apex:commandButton>
    </div>
  </apex:form>
  <apex:pageBlock title="" id="pageBlock">
    <apex:panelBar >
      <apex:repeat var="cv" value="{!contentVersions}">
          <apex:panelBarItem label="{!cv.Title}"><a href="/{!cv.Id}"><img id="image" height="600px" src="/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/{!cv.Id}" title="{!cv.Title}" /></a></apex:panelBarItem>
      </apex:repeat>
    </apex:panelBar>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

I'm so close to making this work properly, please help me :(

Comment: `StandardSetController` it self is giving the pagination capability. Not sure why you use it in a complex way. Check this post http://madhura-priyadarshane.blogspot.com/2015/07/pagination-in-apex-with.html

Comment: `ContentVersion` doesn't permit `StandardSetControllers`. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8706/cannot-use-standardsetcontroller-with-contentversion

Answer (score 2):

In your VF page you have:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="" id="pageBlock">
<apex:panelBar >
  <apex:repeat var="cv" value="{!contentVersions}">
      <apex:panelBarItem label="{!cv.Title}"><a href="/{!cv.Id}"><img id="image" height="600px" src="/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/{!cv.Id}" title="{!cv.Title}" /></a></apex:panelBarItem>
  </apex:repeat>
</apex:panelBar>
```

The `repeat` fetches from `{!contentVersions}` which is defined in your controller as:

```
public static List<ContentVersion> getContentVersions() {
    return [SELECT Id, Title, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion
            WHERE IsLatest = true LIMIT 1000];
}
```

So, it doesn't matter what the Next button does, you ignore its work when you rerender the `pageBlock`

I think you want the `apex:repeat` to bind to a public property `pageContent`

Comment: This does fix the pagination. However: now the images don't display. What if `pageContent` needs to be the recordSetVar for the page, and then set the binding to `content`? Is that likely to cause a change?

Comment: image display sounds like a separate issue - if you type in the browser `/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/someContentversionId` does it display an image suitbale for rendering with HTML img tag?  `recordSetVar` applies to standardSetController

Comment: It sort of works...Strangely, it only works from `https://c.<domain>.visual.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/<someContentVersionId>`, and not from the top-level domain.

Comment: post the question about images in a separate question on SFSE

Answer (score 1):

I was correct with my guess: the `recordSetVar` had to be set to `content`. The images do display now, and paginates up to 2,000 records of ContentVersion object. I'm hoping I can tweak this to use `queryMore()` to bypass the 2,000 record threshold. Thank you very much for your help. :) Below is the updated code for anyone who ever needs this sort of functionality.

ContentVersionFiles.page:

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" recordSetVar="{!content}" readOnly="true" controller="ContentVersionController" showChat="false" showHeader="false" showQuickActionVfHeader="false" sidebar="false">
  <apex:includeScript id="console-js" value="/support/console/35.0/integration.js" />
  <apex:variable var="count" value="{!0}" />
  <apex:form id="topForm">
    <div align="center" style="display:{!IF(NOT(ISNULL(content)), 'block', 'none')}">
      <font size="1pt">Page #:&nbsp;<apex:outputLabel value="{!PageNumber}"/>&nbsp;out of&nbsp;<apex:outputLabel value="{!totalPageNumber}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>
      <apex:commandButton value="Previous" action="{!previousBtnClick}" reRender="pageBlock" disabled="{!previousButtonEnabled}"></apex:commandButton>
      <apex:commandButton value="Next" action="{!nextBtnClick}" reRender="pageBlock" disabled="{!nextButtonDisabled}" ></apex:commandButton>
    </div>
  </apex:form>
  <apex:pageBlock title="Registration Scans" id="pageBlock">
    <apex:panelBar id="scans">
      <apex:repeat var="cv" value="{!pageContent}">
        <apex:variable var="count" value="{!count+1}" />
        <apex:panelBarItem id="barItem" label="{!cv.Title} - #{!count} of {!pageContent.size}" onenter="autoResize(this.id)"><a href="/{!cv.Id}"><img id="image" src="/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/{!cv.Id}" title="{!cv.Title}" /></a></apex:panelBarItem>
      </apex:repeat>
    </apex:panelBar>
  </apex:pageBlock>
  <apex:form id="bottomForm">
    <div align="center" style="display:{!IF(NOT(ISNULL(content)), 'block', 'none')}">
      <font size="1pt">Page #:&nbsp;<apex:outputLabel value="{!PageNumber}"/>&nbsp;out of&nbsp;<apex:outputLabel value="{!totalPageNumber}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>
      <apex:commandButton value="Previous" action="{!previousBtnClick}" disabled="{!previousButtonEnabled}" reRender="pageBlock"></apex:commandButton>
      <apex:commandButton value="Next" action="{!nextBtnClick}" reRender="pageBlock" disabled="{!nextButtonDisabled}" ></apex:commandButton>
    </div>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

ContentVersionController.apxc:

```
public with sharing class ContentVersionController {
    public List<ContentVersion> pageContent { get; set; }
    private ApexPages.StandardSetController controller;
    private List<ContentVersion> content;
    private Integer pageNumber;
    private Integer pageSize;
    private Integer totalPageNumber;

    public ContentVersionController() {
        //controller = new ApexPages.StandardSetController();
        pageNumber = 0;
        totalPageNumber = 0;
        pageSize = 20;
        ViewData();
    }

    public ContentVersionController(ApexPages.StandardSetController con) {
        controller = con;
        pageNumber = 0;
        totalPageNumber = 0;
        pageSize = 20;
        ViewData();
    }

    public static List<ContentVersion> getContentVersions() {
        return [SELECT Id, Title, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion
                WHERE IsLatest = true LIMIT 1000];
        /* Be sure to use "AND OwnerId = '<Id>'"
         * so it will filter out any publicly shared
         * content, like from Chatter. For anything
         * else, you may need to specify what
         * workspace the content is coming from.
         */
    }

    public Integer getPageNumber() {
        return pageNumber;
    }

    public List<ContentVersion> getContent() {
        return pageContent;
    }

    public Integer getPageSize() {
        return pageSize;
    }

    public Boolean getPreviousButtonEnabled() {
        return !(pageNumber > 1);
    }

    public Boolean getNextButtonDisabled() {
        if (content == null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return ((pageNumber * pageSize) >= content.size());
        }
    }

    public Integer getTotalPageNumber() {
        if (totalPageNumber == 0 && content !=null) {
            totalPageNumber = content.size() / pageSize;
            Integer mod = content.size() - (totalPageNumber * pageSize);
            if (mod > 0) {
                totalPageNumber++;
            }
        }
        return totalPageNumber;
    }

    public PageReference ViewData() {
        content = null;
        totalPageNumber = 0;
        BindData(1);
        return null;
    }

    private void BindData(Integer newPageIndex) {
        try {
            if (content == null){
                content = [SELECT Id, Title, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion
                           WHERE IsLatest = true LIMIT 1000];
            }
            pageContent = new List<ContentVersion>();
            transient Integer counter = 0;
            transient Integer min = 0;
            transient Integer max = 0;
            if (newPageIndex > pageNumber) {
                min = pageNumber * pageSize;
                max = newPageIndex * pageSize;
            } else {
                max = newPageIndex * pageSize;
                min = max - pageSize;
                //min = min <>
            }
            for(ContentVersion c : content) {
                counter++;
                if (counter > min && counter <= max){
                    pageContent.add(c);
                }
            }
            pageNumber = newPageIndex;
            if (pageContent == null || pageContent.size() <= 0) {
                ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, 'Data not available for this view.'));
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.FATAL, ex.getMessage()));
        }
    }

    public PageReference nextBtnClick() {
        BindData(pageNumber + 1);
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference previousBtnClick() {
        BindData(pageNumber - 1);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: where is recordSetVar on page definition? It is certainly true that without it - VF doesn't realize that standardSetController is used

Comment: I might have added the file too soon :x I'll have to edit it later

Comment: I'll also add the `readOnly="true"` attribute, since this lets the `List<ContentVersion>` expand from 1,000 objects to 10,000. For anything beyond 10,000 files, you'll have to use the `queryMore()` method for querying beyond what limits Salesforce enforces.